# Determining a winner in a NXN Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I've tried to create a Tic Tac Toe game class with the play and hasWon methods.

```
public class TicTacToe {

private enum State{Blank, X, O}
private int grid;
private State[][] board = new State[grid][grid];
private int moves;


//Default Constructor
public TicTacToe(int grid){

    board = new State[grid][grid];
    moves = 0;
}
public void play(State s, int m, int n){

    if (board[m][n] == State.Blank){
        board[m][n] = s;
    }
    moves++;
}




public boolean hasWon(State[][] board){

    //check winner in rows
    boolean state = false;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(j <= grid) {
        for (i = 0; i <= grid; i++) {
            if (board[j][i] == board[j][i + 1])
                state = true;
            else state = false;
            break;

        }
        if(state == false)
            j++;
        else return true;

    }
    //check winner in columns
    while(j <= grid) {
        for (i = 0; i < grid; i++) {
            if (board[i][j] == board[i + 1][j])
                state = true;
            else state = false;
            break;

        }
        if (state == true)
            j++;
        else return true;
    }
    //check winner in top diagonal
    while(j <= grid && i <= grid){
        if (board[i][j] == board[i+1][j+1])
            state = true;
        else state = false;
        break;

        i++;
        j++;
        return true;
    }


    //check winner in bottom diagonal
    int k = grid;
    int l = grid;
    while(k >= 0 && l >= 0){
        if (board[k][l] == board[k-1][l-1])
            state = true;
        else state = false;
        break;
        k--;
        l--;
        return true;
    }


    return false;
}
```

}

However when called in the Main class the program behaves erratically. Is there a logical problem in the code.

Comment: What does "erratically" mean, exactly?

Comment: In some cases it's giving a winner at others it's not.

Comment: How many do you need to get in a row? 3?

Comment: Well, you are only comparing one diagonal, for starters.

Comment: You might try to implement some unit tests for method `hasWon` and find cases when it is returning incorrect results. It's really useful practice to learn.

Comment: Edited to charge the result array.

Answer (score 0):

When checking your rows with

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (board[j][i] == board[j][i + 1])
        state = true;
}
```

this code always sets the state to true if the last two chars in the row are the same, independently of the chars previous in that row.

The same thing for columns and the diagonal (of which you are checking only as Todd said).

You want to stop comparing values for that row if you find some values that are not equal:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (board[j][i] == board[j][i + 1]) {
        state = true;
    } else {
        state = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Same for rows and diagonal(s).

Edit: 
Furthermore: You are not setting your field grid in the constructor, so it always is 0 and you are not checking your complete rows, columns, diagonals
Missing:

```
this.grid = grid;
```

Comment: Edited to change the result array.

Comment: @Clockwork they way you edited it does not work as the `break` command now causes the loops to stop directly in the first iteration. `break` must be used only when you detect different values.